# Linked List array index 20 is past the end of the array (which contains 20 elements)

Tags: c

I have a question to ask about a part of a code on linked list I didn't understand.
I'm building a doubly linked list and there's a part where I'm stuck hoping that someone could help me.
I'm very new to C though but I hope I can understand the mistake I'm making.

```
struct node
{
    struct node *previous;  // Points to the previous node
    char data[20];
    struct node *next;   // Points out to the next node
}*head, *last;

void insert_beginning(char value[20])
{
    struct node *var, *temp;
    var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    var->data[20]=*value; // Here's my problem

    if (head==NULL)
    {
        head=var;
        head->previous=NULL;
        head->next=NULL;
        last=head;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=var;
        temp->previous=NULL;
        temp->next=head;
        head->previous=temp;
        head=temp;
    }
}
```

on line where it says:

```
 var->data[20]=*value;
```

I'm having a note saying: array index 20 is past the end of the array (which contains 20 elements)

Is there something I'm missing out?
Can somebody explain me what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in C (and many other languages) have a zero based index system. An array of size 20 elements has indices ranging from 0 to 19 inclusive. This is just how it works - thus index 20 would point at the 21st element.

Answer (score 0):

As already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20730941) by [mathematician1975](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1342730/mathematician1975), in an array of 20 objects, the maximum array index that can be assigned is 19 because arrays are zero-based, not one-based.

However, your whole assignment is probably misguided. It looks like you are wanting to copy the string from `value` into the linked list node, so you should probably replace:

```
var->data[20] = *value;
```

with:

```
strcpy(var->data, value);
```

assuming you trust your inputs (`value` in this case), or using a bounded copy such as:

```
strncpy(var->data, value, sizeof(var->data)-1);
var->data[sizeof(var->data)-1] = '\0';
```

to ensure you have a null-terminated string in place without any risk of overflowing the buffer. (Be cautious with `strncpy()` copying small strings into large buffers; it does a lot of work.  But large means kilobytes or more data, maybe hundreds of bytes; 20 is not large.)

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out